# Tcl tclsh Set Up

Tags: windows, eclipse, installation, tcl, tclsh

I am just starting out in Tcl and am trying to properly configure an editor and interpreter for use. On Tcl's download page it is recommended to use ActiveState's ActiveTcl, but I am learning Tcl for possible production use and want to avoid paying for it.

I tried setting up Eclipse's DLTK to use for learning, but from what I found I need to direct it to the tclsh executable to use it as the interpreter. In Tcl version 8.6.6, I can't find anything that will work. The supposed formats (I'm on Windows) should follow what's seen [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl0a.html), as I've seen this a few examples/tutorials.

As a last resort, I tried following the Windows instructions [here](https://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/compile.html) to use my MS Visual Studio 2015 work with this, but there is no such vcvars file (what's asked for when reading makefile.vc after downloading Tcl).

I would really like to use Eclipse for this, so I guess my question is as follows: How do you use tclsh as a Tcl interpreter in Tcl 8.6.6?

Comment: ActiveTcl is free to use for this sort of thing. I use it with Eclipse on OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveTcl isn't a pay-for product. (ActiveState have some of those, but their language distribution isn't one of them as long as you're not after a support plan.)

To configure Eclipse to use the right installed version of Tcl, go to the **Tcl → Interpreters** page in the main **Preferences** panel. That lets you **Add…** an interpreter, which essentially just requires you to find where the `tclsh` you want to use is on your filesystem, and to give it a name. I use names like “Tcl 8.6” in my installation, so it isn't exactly rocket science. The DLTK system can find out pretty much everything else once it knows where the interpreter implementation is, but if you have several set up (e.g., I have both 8.5 and 8.6) then you'll need to say which one is default using the checkboxes in the list in the **Interpreters** pane.
<sub><sub>(I've verified the above against Eclipse Neon running on OSX, but I don't think it will vary very much with other versions or platforms.)</sub></sub>

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. But could you clarify one more thing for me? The free version of ActiveTcl says "for non-production use only". If I were to introduce this for basic business use but did not need the support (save costs), would I still be able to use this for free or do I have to find another way?